# How to display a message box in view from controller?

Tags: javascript, jquery, grails, groovy, grails-orm

After a user enters some numbers and other data on a form a total is calculated.  The user might also choose to enter a discount amount.  I use a jQuery AJAX method to send all the data to the `getTotal` method in the `Load` controller.  If the user entered a discount amount greater than the calculated total I want a message box to pop up (similar to a JavaScript `alert` box) saying the discount must be less than the total.  Is there any clean way to do this from the controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I did.  In my view I have the following code in one of my JavaScript methods.  I use jQuery's `getJSON` instead of `ajax` because it seemed to fit better (cleaner).

```
$.getJSON(
  "/truckingmanagement/load/getTotal",
  {cargoSource:cargoSource, cargo:cargo, haulRate:haulRate, tonnage:tonnage, mileage:mileage, discount:discount, taxExempt:taxExempt},
  function(result) {
    if(result.message != null){
      alert(result.message);
      $("#discount").val("");
      $("#totalCell").html(result.total);
    }
    else{
      $("#totalCell").html(result.total);
    }
  });
```

I my controller I still used the `render` method inside my closure, but modified it for JSON, making sure to `import grails.converters.*`.

```
render(contentType:"text/json") {
    total = g.textField(name: 'total', value: totalBill, readonly: 'readonly')
    message = errorMessage
}
```

The `totalBill` value has been calculated prior to calling `render`, and `errorMessage` is just a string that contains a message based on what the error was (negative discount value or discount value greater than total) or no message at all.  Thus if the message is `null` no message will be displayed.

Answer (score 1):

No. You'd want to send a result back in your ajax response that tells the client to display your message box.  Then you'd probably use JavaScript to show it.  There are a lot of jQuery plugins for displaying message boxes.  For example: [jQueryUI's Dialog](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/).

Comment: Right now my controller uses `render` to render the total in a text field, then sends that back as HTML via AJAX. How do I render the total AND render the message in the same AJAX call?

Comment: You'd need to return a different set of data.  For example, some JSON that contains the data and something that says to show the message box.  Use JavaScript to update the textfield rather then sending the entire HTML across.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is technically possible to have your controller generate javasacript as response to an ajax call, but that'd be a very ugly way to do it.

Better is to send JSON. Something like:

```
result = []
result.success = total >= discount
result.total = total
render result as JSON
```

And in the Ajax call, check for success, show the total if successful, show the message if not.